# Как решить проблему с анимацией?

Tags: html, css

В момент пропадания drodown, визуально он пропадает, но в реальности он  на странице остается еще около 1-2 секунд. Т.е. после скрытия drodown, можно навести курсор на место, где ранее был drodown и тем самым снова показать этот самый drodown.

Как сделать, чтобы drodown сразу пропадал, как только пропал визуально?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dropdown {
  position: inline-block;
  display: relative;
}

.dropdown__container {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.dropdown:hover>.dropdown__container {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Dropdown test</a>

    <div class="dropdown__container">
      I am Dropdown
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае, не прибегая к js, можно использовать `pointer-events`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dropdown {
  position: inline-block;
  display: relative;
}

.dropdown__container {
  visible: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown:hover>.dropdown__container {
  visible: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Dropdown test</a>

    <div class="dropdown__container">
      I am Dropdown
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```